# ParaChain Transfer assets with XCM

Tags: xcm

I followed this tutorial (https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/transfer-assets-with-xcm/), but got an erorr, so can't complete it.

Could anyone please solve my problem?

1. Parachain Does not have `sudo extrinsic`.
   Using `v0.9.37` version(Polkadot + Substrate-prachain) parachain does not have it in extrinsic
   how do i use sudo?
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the `substrate-parachain-template` runtime and it does not implement the sudo pallet. Please jump into `lib.rs` on `runtime` folder and you might see that there is no `Config` trait for `sudo-pallet`, like this:

```rust
impl pallet_sudo::Config for Runtime {
    type RuntimeEvent = RuntimeEvent;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
}
```

Please have in mind that adding a pallet to the runtime implies other steps that you can check [here](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet/) as an example reference.

Comment: It is not easy to follow that link for beginner
For example
`pallet-nicks = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.37" }`
this line how to apply as sudo version..?

Comment: No worries, let me provide further assistance. There are some steps for adding a pallet into a runtime which are shown in the doc that I shared with you, this document does the whole process but instead of doing it with `pallet-sudo` it does it with `pallet-nick`. This would transponse pretty okey to most points, like integrating to `runtime` dependencies on `Cargo.toml`, adding to `features` and so. The only point which will differ heavily is the configuration of the pallet, since in the tutorial `pallet-nick` is being configured and in our case we want to do it for `pallet-sudo`.

Comment: On my answer you will find an example of how to configure `pallet-sudo` and just to be super clear [this](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/add-a-pallet/#:~:text=to%20track%20balances.-,Implement%20the%20configuration%20for%20Nicks,-Now%20that%20you) is the section of the tutorial I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [read](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-parachain/open-message-passing-channels/) this . Here it's written that the pallet is not included by default if you use the substrate-parachain-template to build your node. To add the Sudo pallet, you must update the runtime/src/lib.rs and node/src/chain_spec.rs files. For the runtime, you can implement the configuration trait and modify the construct_runtime macro, similar to how you would add any other pallet.

[Here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/Cargo.toml#L67) is the dependency of sudo . You need to add [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/src/lib.rs#L1355) in your runtime/lib.rs and after that you need to add sudo in the construct_runtime like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/rococo/src/lib.rs#L1480). In the last, you need to add [this](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1107) in the chain_spec.rs